# why is one side of my parented object deformed on animation but the other one is fine?

Tags: animation, rigging

i'm new to rigging and animation and encountered this problem but i dont really know what to search/ the keyword for this type of error
[image]

[test animation.blend](https://filedoge.com/download/de6512544fe95783b9b42bd9e4e0a21eea0883e7dfca58a78e2fa6e727a8a18febd186cedf57c93ade23)

Comment: Pls upload your blend file because you didn’t give us any useful information ….so we can just guess around…could be wrong weight painting….

Comment: hi, i've edited the post to include the files

Answer (score 0):

It's because bones from the one leg affects vertices from the other:

[image]